# Assist with PHP date showing wrong day of week (z) from unix timestamp

Tags: php, date

Hello I am experiencing a bizarre problem I do not know how to approach what to do about it, so I am hoping maybe someone on here has seen something like this and has some input...,

Basically I have a database which has records that are basketball games.  On each game is a unix timestamp.

When I display the schedule on webpage - PHP loops through records from the database to find the ones we want and then pulls down the records.

Before the loop i set the timezone to America/New_York

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

To display the date string, time string and day of week we do the following:

```
    $date99=date('m/d/y',$ts2);
    $time99=date('h:i A',$ts2);
    $weekday=date('D',$ts2);
```

$ts2 is the unix timestamp value it is pulling from the database for each game record.

It seems like PHP is always displaying the correct date string ($date99) and the correct time string ($time99)

And the "weekday" does work properly sometimes.  But some people are reporting that the weekday shown is incorrect.

So I am not sure what could be wrong.  From what we are seeing - it is getting the timezone correctly and is consistently displaying the proper date string and time string.  But some people are seeing it where the weekday is showing the wrong day.

It just seems bizarre that PHP would always display the date string and time string correctly - but then sometimes mess up on the weekday.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks so much,  Gerard

*** update 1:04am est 11/24/2017

by request here is the data from one record where this problem was reported:

unix timestamp :  1517963400
date string:  02/06/18   (correct)
time string: 07:30pm (correct)
day of week: sometimes shown as "Tue"(correct) and sometimes shown as "Wed" (incorrect)

Please note while the displaying of the day of week is inconsistent - it always shows the correct date string and correct time string...

Comment: _"some people are seeing it where the weekday is showing the wrong day"_ - Any example?

Comment: We need more information. Log what you output. Is it off by one day or one year?

Comment: thanks guys - I edited the question to show an example of what is happening....

Comment: What timezone did you store it as in the database?

Comment: Ummm - I did not store a timezone in the database - just the unix timestamp - and then i set the timezone at the top of the script as I have shown in the question... does that help?

Comment: Hello Guys:  I never did find the actual cause of this - but your input did help  guide me a little - the problem was each record display - it depended on php using timezone setting to properly interpret the timestamp, and it seems that with high traffic - sometimes that can fail (it is the ONLY explanation that can explain it that I can see)...what I ended up doing was storing the day of week as a string on the record; so php did not have to do any interpretation on it when it pulled it down...